# Is accessing Models from Other Controllers Considered Breaking the MVC Framework

Tags: model-view-controller

Quick question: Is it wrong for a controller to access two or more Models? Let's say there are two Two controller with each have their own models. Accessing the model of the other controller breaks the rule in MVC? Should I access the model through a controller (if HMVC) the proper way of getting to that model?

Answer (score 0):

No, having multiple controllers interacting with same [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) (what you call "models") is not against basic ideas of MVC pattern. Thing is, usually your controllers should not interact with domain objects directly. They should be contained in [services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_%28systems_architecture%29), which let you isolate presentation layer (mostly controllers, views and templates) from the model layer.

Comment: What I am planning is there's a template controller and controllers, which handles the model calls and directs to other processes. I would guess that would be the service controller that you speak off.

Comment: No, it wouldn't.  Services are part of model layer. I actually have no idea, what "template controllers" and "model controllers" are. You cannot just make up terms and expect people to understand them.

Comment: Sorry. The framework I am using is FuelPHP. There's a controller that explicitly used for building templates and I was thinking of breaking the code into smaller bits, thus there's a HMVC in my question. Anyway, thanks for the help. I'll let this question sit for a day and come back if there are other people who want to share their opinion.